# How can I download a file on a click event using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-colaboratory

I want to download each of the files from the website: https://massdot.app.box.com/s/21j0q5di9ewzl0abt6kdh5x8j8ok9964

When you enter the website there are a few links which you can click on that redirect you to another website with the "Download" which you can then download the files from. I want to automate this process using Python but I do not know how. I use Google Colab. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible solutions:

```py
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update 
!apt install chromium-chromedriver

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get('https://massdot.app.box.com/s/21j0q5di9ewzl0abt6kdh5x8j8ok9964')
# download all files(CSVs for public download.zip)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[aria-label="Download"]'))).click()
```

Output:

```
CSVs for public download.zip
```

Next, you can use zipfile module to extract the contents of the archive and work with the resulting data.

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile('CSVs for public download.zip') as myzip:
    myzip.extractall('/content')
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! However I get an error:  ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button class="btn SharedFolderActionBar-download" type="submit" aria-label="Download" data-resin-target="bulkdownload" tabindex="0">...</button> is not clickable at point (748, 100). Other element would receive the click: <a

Comment: @jaralepi I tested it again and it works ok. Try adding a longer timeout to `WebDriverWait(driver, 20)`
And for convenience split code into cells, for example like this: [imgur link](https://i.imgur.com/biZk7KC.png)